# What's the disadvantage of doing git init in the desktop directory?

Tags: git

I'm using win10 and I have a folder called `UTM` putting on the desktop directory. I want to push it to my repo in github. So I `cd` to the desktop directory and do `git init`. But my friend tell me I should not do that. I ask him why. He couldn't give me a reason but just said people usually don't do that. So I'm curious is there any disadvantage to create an empty Git repo in the desktop directory? If I don't do `git add` to the other files, it should be safe, doesn't it?

Comment: This is a disaster for an opportunity (pun intended).

Comment: I mean.... without you noticing, you will add some files from your desktop that you never intended to and before you realize it, it will be published on some repo out there (say, github or bitbucket or elsewhere).

Comment: No problem from the technical point of view, anyway.

Comment: @hyde Yea, my friend said I don't understand `git init`. I guess this is what he means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git init` is a *local* operation, so it has no bearing on GitHub.

Until you are a remote (`cd UTM; git remote add origin https://github.com/<you>/<your_repo>`), and actually add, command and then push, nothing will leave your PC without you knowing.

But it should be done in the folder you intent to push, not on "`Desktop`" (which has all sorts of files you might not want to push)

And that supposes the remote GitHub repo is a new empty one.

Answer (score 0):

You can track changes in a directory tree using git after you do `git init` on it. The question is not really whether there are "advantages" or "disadvantages" to making your Desktop a git repository. The question is whether you want to track changes to all files and directories on your Desktop. If you do, then `git init` and the rest is something you can do. If you don't, then don't do it.